# Ember toggle navigation in nested route

Tags: ember.js

I have a top navigation bar that I'm calling in the Application Template as a partial.

```
{{partial "topnav"}}
{{outlet}}
```

I'd like to remove that top navigation downstream in one of my nested routes.  How do I do this?

**Clarification**

- I don't want to toggle the navigation, I want it to never render in the downstream route.
- I'd like the solution to work with multiple routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This goes in the route that you want to turn off the topnav:

```
beforeModel: ->
    this.controllerFor('application').toggleProperty('topNav')
```

Then you define a property in the application controller:

```
topNav: true
```

which you refer to in the template like so:

```
{{#if topNav}}
  {{partial "topnav"}}
{{/if}}
{{outlet}}
```

Comment: the component can also check the current route by using https://api.emberjs.com/ember/release/classes/RouterService current design patterns are moving away from controllers

Answer (score 4):

Ember installs the current route name and path on your app's `ApplicationController` as the properties `currentRouteName` and `currentPath`.

So in your `ApplicationController`, you can create a computed property like this:

```
isCurrentRouteX: Ember.computed.equal('currentRouteName', 'X');
```

where `X` is the route on which you want to preclude the partial.

Finally, in your `application.hbs`, you can simply do this:

```
{{#unless isCurrentRouteX}}
  {{partial "topnav"}}
{{/unless}}
{{outlet}}
```

Comment: To expand on this, what if I had several routes downstream that I wanted to do this with?  Instead of making a long list of routes in the logic in the Application controller, is there a way to toggle a property in the Application controller from the downstream controller?

Comment: yeah, send an action to the application route and have it modify the application controller

Comment: Won't this cause the navbar to be on the screen momentarily while the action is triggered? ie. the navbar will render then be hidden, versus not being rendered at all, which is what I really want.  This answer is what I'm looking for, but I want to know how to get it to work with multiple routes..

Comment: As @kingpin2k example shows, you can bubble up an action from a nested route to the application route and handle in in application route or application controller.

Comment: You can send the action during the transition, which will set the property before the page is rendered, meaning you would never see it.

Answer (score 1):

Create an action in the application route which toggles a property on the application controller which controls whether or not to display the partial.

Here's an example:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/bososaga/1/edit

Comment: I want to turn the navigation off from a nested route, not the application route.

Comment: I turned it off from the index route... the application route just handles the actual hiding/showing.